# Algebra square roots addition problem $\sqrt {x+15} + \sqrt x = 15$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, radicals

Saw this algebra problem in an ad, and don't immediately remember how to solve it:

$\sqrt {x+15} + \sqrt x = 15$

I at least remember that you can't simply square everything, i.e., if a + b = c, it does not necessarily follow that $\ a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

Of course, it does follow that $(\sqrt {x+15} + \sqrt x)^2 = 15^2 = 225$, but not sure if that's the right direction to go in, or where to go from there if it is. I don't want anyone to solve it for me, but please throw me a hint if you'd be so kind - thanks!

Comment: Your idea is solid.  expand $(\sqrt {x+15}+\sqrt x)^2$ and see where that leads.

Comment: Note:  if this appeared in an ad, my guess would be that you were meant to search for integer solutions.  That's not a generally useful method, but it works here.

Comment: An ad from Brilliant ?

Comment: $x=49$ is a solution by "inspired guess" and it is the only solution since $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+15}$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Hint: let $a := \sqrt{x+15}$ and $b := \sqrt{x}$.  Then the equation gives $a+b = 15$, and also $a^2 - b^2 = 15 = (a-b)(a+b)$, so $a-b = 1$.

Answer (score 12):

$$\sqrt { x+15 } +\sqrt { x } =15\\ { \left( \sqrt { x+15 }  \right)  }^{ 2 }={ \left( 15-\sqrt { x }  \right)  }^{ 2 }\\$$

> $$ x+15=225-30\sqrt { x } +x\\ 30\sqrt { x } =210\\ \sqrt { x } =7\\ x=49$$

Comment: OP: "I don't want anyone to solve it for me." Oh well.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs,I don't see any problem  to give it as a  "hint"  or solving it

Comment: I only have an issue if the OP specifically requests not to see a full solution. Whatever ‍♀️

Answer (score 8):

Let
\begin{align}
   \sqrt {x+15} + \sqrt x &= 15 \\
   \sqrt {x+15} - \sqrt x &= y
\end{align}

Multiplying, we get

> $(x+15) - x = 15y$

Which simplifies to

> $$ y = 1$$

So
\begin{align}
   \sqrt {x+15} + \sqrt x &= 15 \\
   \sqrt {x+15} - \sqrt x &= 1
\end{align}

Subtracting, we get

> $2 \sqrt x = 14$

Which simplifies to

> x = 49

Comment: You could have skipped $y$ by multiplying both sides with $\sqrt{x+15}-\sqrt{x}$ instead which leads to the equation $\sqrt{x+15}-\sqrt{x} = 1$

Comment: @skyking Yes. I'm not sure it is a significantly better way to go though.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x+15}+\sqrt{x}$.

Hence, $f$ is increasing function, which says that our equation has at most one root.

But easy to check that ... is a root. Thus, it's an unique root of our equation.

Comment: The OP wrote "*I don't want anyone to solve it for me, but please throw me a hint*". Previous replies at least hid the actual answer behind spoiler tags.

Comment: @dxiv I fixed my post. Is now it relevant?

Comment: The 2nd part (now edited out) was the one with the full answer so, yes, this is closer to a "hint" as requested.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is that the two radicals are of the form $\sqrt{x+a}$. If you have
$$
\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt{x+b}=k \tag{1}
$$
with $a>b$ and $k>0$, then you can multiply both sides by $\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x+b}$, getting
$$
(x+a)-(x+b)=k(\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x+b})
$$
so
$$
\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x+b}=\frac{a-b}{k}\tag{2}
$$
Now look at equations (1) and (2)…

---

This would also work for equations of the form
$$
\sqrt{mx+a}+\sqrt{mx+b}=k
$$
or
$$
\sqrt{mx+a}-\sqrt{mx+b}=k
$$
but not if the coefficients of $x$ are different in the two radicals. In that case, squaring (and hoping for the best) is the way to go.

---

You could also square: $(\sqrt{x+15}+\sqrt{x})^2=15^2$ so $2x+15+2\sqrt{x(x+15)}=225$ and finally
$$
\sqrt{x(x+15)}=105-x
$$
Squaring again,
$$
x^2+15x=11025-210x+x^2
$$
or
$$
225x=11025
$$
Not really a big deal, but the above methods has smaller figures.

Comment: Okay, this is ringing a bell- what rule explains how we get from  $(\sqrt{x+15}+\sqrt{x})^2$ to $2x+15+2\sqrt{x(x+15)}$, again? That's the part I was getting stuck on - figuring out what I can translate $(\sqrt{x+15}+\sqrt{x})^2$ to. In general, if you have an expression like, say: $(x^5 + \sqrt x - 3x + 7)^4$, what are the rules for translating that into an expression without parens?

Comment: @Cmaso $(\sqrt{x+15}+\sqrt{x})^2=(\sqrt{x+15})^2+2\sqrt{x+15}\,\sqrt{x}+(\sqrt{x})^2$.

Comment: Because it's always true that  $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ - now I remember  -thanks much!